# Replacing max number with min number in 2d array.Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write code for replacing these max and min nubmers and then print new 2d array,any thoughs?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Unesite velicinu n niza:");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Unesite velicinu m niza:");
    int m = input.nextInt();

    int [][] niz = new int [n][m];
    int max = niz[0][0];

    for (int i =0;i<niz.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j<niz[i].length;j++) {
            niz [i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*50);
            System.out.print(niz [i][j] + " ");
            if (niz [i][j] > max){
                max = niz [i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
    System.out.println("Najveci broj je: " + max);

    int min = niz [0][0];

    for (int i =0;i<niz.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j<niz[i].length;j++) {
            if (niz [i][j]<min){
                min = niz[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Najmanji broj je: " + min);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: yeah,its all in the question on top of the post,it prints out matrix,finds max and min number in it,then i'm needed to exchange max and min numbers(just moving max number to min position and vice versa)then print out a new matrix with these changes

Comment: Can you explain in what way(s) this is not performing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine `min` and `max` in your initial array population (I'd use `Math.min(int, int)` and `Math.max(int, int)` respectively). Something like

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int [][] niz = new int [n][m];
for (int i =0;i<niz.length;i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<niz[i].length;j++) {
        niz [i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*50);
        System.out.print(niz [i][j] + " ");
        max = Math.max(max, niz[i][j]);
        min = Math.min(min, niz[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Then you can swap `min` and `max` (and display) with another loop. Like

```
for (int i =0;i<niz.length;i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<niz[i].length;j++) {
        if (niz[i][j] == max) {
            niz[i][j] = min;
        } else if (niz[i][j] == min) {
            niz[i][j] = max;
        }
        System.out.print(niz [i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```